# counting bitstrings of specific length

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Is my solution right refarding this question?

How many bitstrings of length 77 are there that start with 010 (i.e, have 010 at position 1, 2, and 3) or have 101 at positions 2,3, and 4, or have 010 at positions 3, 4, and 5?

the answeer i got is |AuBuC| = |A| + |B| + |C| -|A and B| - |A and C| - | B and C| + |A and B and C|

= 2^74 + 2^74 + 2^74 - 2^71 - 2^71 - 2^71 + 2^68

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you explain how precisely you get the 74, 71 and 68 exponents ?

Comment: the first bit string  is length three and there are 77 bit strings to choose from so 77-3 =74 bit string and we know a bit can be 0 or 1 so that is why we have 2^74

Comment: and for the 71 we know cardinality of A and B is 3 +3 = 6 therefore 77-6 = 71 so we get 2^71

Comment: you forget a detail, the cardinality of "A and B" may not be  6...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the bits 6 to 77, you have

```
00000
00001
00010 C
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000 A
01001 A
01010 A B C
01011 A B
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001
10010 C
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010 B C
11011 B
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

So in total 8.2^72 = 2^75 solutions.

By inclusion/exclusion, (4 + 4 + 4 - 2 - 1 - 2 + 1).2^72 = 2^75.

Comment: why is your bit string length 5? and why is the solution 8X2^72. I used the inclusion and exclusion rule. I dont really get your solution. can you eleborate?

Comment: The factor 8 is obvious: count the strings. Length is 5 because the 72 remaining bits are unconstrained.

Comment: how did you get  2^73 - 2^72 - 2^73 + 2^71? i just want to know how I did it wrong

Comment: I gave you a hint above and you can check the counts for all combinations of A, B and C from the exhaustive list.